# Large-time limit of the general solution of an ODE is a fixed-point. Is the fixed-point stable?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

This question might well have an obvious affirmative answer (or an obvious counterexample!), which at present I cannot see. Suppose I have a first-order ODE
$$
u'(t)=f(u)
$$
whose *general* solution depends on one arbitrary constant $A$. Suppose that I take the large-$t$ limit of this general solution, and I find that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}u_{gen}(t)=u^\star\ ,
$$
where $u^\star$ is a number (which does not depend on $A$ anymore). Furthermore, $u^\star$ is a fixed-point of my ODE, namely $f(u^\star)=0$. Can I immediately conclude that $u^\star$ is a *stable* fixed point? Or are there (sufficiently pathological, I guess) cases where the large-$t$ limit is an unstable fixed-point irrespective of the initial conditions? Thanks for your help, folks.

Comment: I think that If all initial conditions end up in $u^\star$, then, by definition, $u^\star$ is an asymptotically stable fixed point.

Comment: you can check $f'(u^\star)$. If $f'(u^\star) < 0$, then $u^\star$ is asymptotically stable. If $f'(u^\star) > 0$, then $u^\star$ is unstable.

Comment: What if $f(u^\star)=f'(u^\star)=0$?

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro Actually, there examples of differential equations for which all solutions tend to an unstable equilibrium point.

Comment: @Jonas could you elaborate more on this, please?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
x'=x^2-y^2,\\
y'=2xy.
\end{cases}
$$
In order to draw the phase portrait just rewrite it in the form $z'=z^2$ on the complex plane.

This is not yet what you want (depends on what you want...) since the negative part of the horizontal axis tends to infinity. But you can see the differential equation on the $2$-sphere, in which case it has exactly one equilibrium point and all orbits tend to the equilibrium point (both when the time goes to $+\infty$ and to $-\infty$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, can you show explicitly that the *general* solution $(x(t),y(t))$ of your ODE system for $t\to\infty$ converges to the unstable fixed point [$(0,0)$, right?] *irrespective* of the initial conditions? I do not see it...

Comment: Check that the solutions are $x(t)=-(a+t)/[(a + t)^2 + b^2]$, $y(t)=b/[(a + t)^2 + b^2]$, with $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your help (+1). Any thoughts about the purely 1D case?

Comment: Ah, if that's what you want, in the $1$-dimensional case there is no counterexample on the line but again there is a counterexample on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat more elementary example, where $r,\theta$ are polar coordinates:
$$
\dot r=r(1-r)\\
\dot \theta=\sin^2\theta/2.
$$
Point $(1,0)$ attracts all the orbits except the one starting at the origin. But is unstable.

Comment: All except one, that's why I didn't give this example.

Comment: @Jonas, yes, of course.

Comment: @Artem Many thanks for your example (+1). Any thoughts about the purely 1D case?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo In the autonomous case all the solutions are monotone, so there will be no such examples. It is quite easy to come up with an example of $x'=f(t,x)$ such that zero will be attractive at $t\to\infty$ but not asymptotically stable. For asymptotical stability solution should stay near this point for all $t>t_0$